# std::function overloads have similar conversions

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm in the process of writing up an STL-like library for learning purposes. All of the collections extend a class called `Iterable` which contains wrapping functions for all of the functions found in `<algorithm>`. For example, it allows `vec.each([](T t){...});` which I strongly prefer over the verbose `std::for_each`. The function giving me problems is `count` - I want to overload `Iterable::count` so it combines the behaviour of both `std::count` and `std::count_if` depending on the argument type but I'm running into a strange error.

Iterable.h

```
virtual int count(const T& value) const {
    return std::count(begin(), end(), value);
}
virtual int count(std::function<bool(T&)> predicate) {
    return std::count_if(begin(), end(), predicate);
}
virtual int count(std::function<bool(const T&)> predicate) const {
    return std::count_if(begin(), end(), predicate);
}
```

main.cpp

```
Vector<int> vec; // extends Iterable
vec.add(0);
vec.add(1);
vec.count([](int i){ return i == 0; }); // compiles and works fine
vec.count(0); // error c2666: 3 overloads have similar conversions
```

I should note that changing the `count_if` wrapper function names to `count_if` does work and resolves the ambiguity, but I'd prefer to have them named `count` and also to figure out why there is ambiguity in the first place.

From what I interpret, the compiler is trying to make a new `std::function` using the `template <class F> function(F f)` ctor, then runs into the ambiguity. Is that the case? It seems odd since the line below fails to compile as well.

```
std::function<bool(int)> f(0); // error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

Any insights or potential fixes are much appreciated.

Forgot to say; using visual studio 2012, nov 2012 ctp compiler

Comment: Why are you writing range primitives that rely on `virtual` functions and type-erased `std::function`s?  You'll end up with code slower than Java!  All the overhead, with no runtime on-the-fly optimization!

Comment: @Yakk how would it be slow? All the code does is hand it off to functions from `<algorithm>`. It'd be the same as writing `std::for_each` with a lambda.

Comment: No, that isn't what it does.  A lambda is not a `std::function`.  A lambda is an unnameable class with an inline `operator()`.  A `std::function` is a tool of type erasure.  Similarly, a virtual method that calls a template function is not the same as a call to a template function.  You are hiding a bunch of information from the compiler by hiding it behind abstraction, then asking it to optimize with crumbs, and demanding it do extra work while you are at it.

Comment: @Yakk: I have to disagree: these aren't abstraction layers. They're just distraction layers.

Comment: @Yakk thanks. I'll change them to template functions then.

Comment: @JerryCoffin An `Iterable` abstraction, even with type erasure overhead, could be marginally useful: the problem above is that it is forced on every use case.

Comment: @Yakk: As an abstraction (e.g., in the form of a concept) it can be useful. As a base class, by itself, it's pretty useless--since it doesn't specify otherwise, you're stuck with it being pretty much equivalent to an `InputIterator`, which is *almost* always unnecessarily restricted. I think to get close to useful, you'd (at least) need a whole series of `InputIerable`, `ForwardIterable`, `ReverseIterable`, `RandomIterable`, just about like the concepts we already (informally) apply to iterators.

Comment: @JerryCoffin ya, I wouldn't make it a base class.  I'd make it a type-erasure trick, where `ForwardIterableView<int>` could type-erase any `int` forward-iterable container.  Might have `IterableView<int>` that is a forward iterable view that can be "upgrade" (maybe) to the other iterable views.  Very limited use, because you really, really want the loop body code in the same scope as the loop code.

Comment: @Yakk: As a type-erasure trick, it might stand some chance--at that point, you're basically doing library-based concepts. Specifically, you can apply it when you consume the data rather than requiring the collection designer to guess how you might want to consume the data. As a base class, it quickly leads to embarrassing situations like Java's "no, a Map really isn't a Collection."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that 0 is ambiguous here, it can be interpreted as a null pointer or an int, which makes it match both the `std::function` constructor and the more general `const T& value` (both require a conversion).

If you don't want to change the interface, you can just create a very simple function template to deduce and dispatch the arguments.

C++11 version:

```
template<typename U>
int count(U&& value) const {
    return count_impl(std::forward<U>(value));
}
```

This works because the function template type deduction rules don't have that ambiguity, they never treat 0 as a null pointer.

So your interface is now:

```
virtual int count_impl(const T& value) const {
    return std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), value);
}
virtual int count_impl(std::function<bool(T&)> predicate) {
    return std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), predicate);
}
virtual int count_impl(std::function<bool(const T&)> predicate) const {
    return std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), predicate);
}

template<typename U>
int count(U&& value) const {
    return count_impl(std::forward<U>(value));
}
```

And you can use it naturally:

```
int main(){
    Vector<int> vec; // extends Iterable
    vec.count([](int i){ return i == 0; }); // compiles and works fine
    vec.count(0); // no problem, calls virtual int count_impl(const T& value) const
}
```

Comment: Are you testing in MSVC2012 or some actual C++11 compiler?  :)

Comment: It compiles on  MSVC 19.00.23008 (http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/), but unfortunately I don't have access to MSVC2012 to test. Is MSVC 2012 pre C++11?

Comment: @tux3: It's not precisely pre-Standard C++11, since it has some features implemented including all revisions.  But other features are entirely missing.  (Also remember that Microsoft has a many months test and release cycle, it seems that all work on new features for VS2012 had ended before the final vote took place and only bugfixes were ongoing)

Comment: If needed std::forward and move semantics can be removed and it should still work. Does anyone have MSVC 2012 to check if it actually compiles :) ?

Comment: This does indeed compile, and work as expected. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that MSVC2012/2013 has the "greedy" `std::function` ctor.  You are testing it on MSVC2015, which has implemented a fix to the C++11 standard in C++14 there.

Comment: @twentylemon I'm surprised if the above works in MSVC2012!  Ah, maybe perfect matching -- `T const&` requires no conversion, so wins.  Try passing `0.0` instead of `0`, I suspect you'll get a compiler error again.  If not that, then `struct Evil{ operator int()const{return 0;} };`.  And the `const` non`const` cases are handled because the one matching the `this` type is preferred.

Comment: @tux3 http://goo.gl/ElTkRS First, C++03 doesn't have `std::function`.  With `struct Evil` we have an early C++11 failing, because both `std::function` and `int` are equally valid for `Evil`.  [here](http://goo.gl/pWDLX5) in a more modern C++11 compiler (well C++14), it compiles.  The problem is that both `int` and `std::function<?>` are equally valid overloads for a type that has a user-defined conversion to `int` in MSVC2012 and early C++11 compilers.  `0.0` isn't a user-defined conversion, so the to-int one wins out.  Still, because `T const&`, this is only going to be sometimes annoying.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, I was not making much sense with my C++03 talk, I'm not sure how to call what mix of features MSVC 2012 supports. You're right about Evil and 0.0 failing too, I was testing on bleeding edge compilers and saw different headers, sorry about that! So, that's an annoying situation.

Answer (score 4):

`std::function<Sig>` in the published C++11 standard without errata contains a constructor that thinks it can consume anything, as far as its signature is concerned.  If you pass it things it cannot consume (things that are not callable), it fails to compile.

Overload resolution occurs earlier (based on shallower information) than the compile failure.  It matches on signatures, not implementations.

A bug report and a fix was proposed, so some C++11 compilers can fix this, and all C++14 compilers must fix this.

VS2012 has limited SFINAE overload resolution capabilities.  But one approach would look like:

```
template<class Sig, class=void>
struct is_filter_on : std::false_type{};
template<class F, class Arg>
struct is_filter_on< F(Arg),
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<
    typename std::result_of<F(Arg)>::type
  ,bool>::value>::type
> : std::true_type{};
```

which is an attempt at a traits class that tells you if `F(Arg)` is a `bool`-returning "filter" on values of type `Arg`.

```
template<class X>
size_t count(X&& x) const {
  return count( std::forward<X>(x), is_filter_on< X&(T const&) >{} );
}
template<class X>
size_t count(X&& x) {
  return count( std::forward<X>(x), is_filter_on< X&(T&) >{} );
}

template<class F>
size_t count(F&& f, std::true_type) const {
  return std::count_if( begin(), end(), std::forward<F>(f) );
}
template<class F>
size_t count(F&& f, std::true_type) {
  return std::count_if( begin(), end(), std::forward<F>(f) );
}
template<class X>
size_t count(X&& x, std::false_type) const {
  return std::count( begin(), end(), std::forward<X>(x) );
}
template<class X>
size_t count(X&& x, std::false_type) {
  return std::count( begin(), end(), std::forward<X>(x) );
}
```

but I have no idea of MSVC2012 will work with the above.

Here I use tag dispatching to pick which version of `count` I call.  The traits class `is_filter_on` does a test to determine if the pseudo-expression `F(Arg)` is filter-like.  If so, we dispatch to the `std::count_if`.  Otherwise, we dispatch to the `std::count` version.

Comment: The bug, as described, is still present in MSVC2013

Comment: @marom yep.  There was some wording that it is partially fixed in 2015 (up to "expression SFINAE", which means "mostly fixed, except in annoying corner cases").